# Randomly logging out

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, logout, xubuntu

My Xubuntu 10.04 system logs me out seemingly at random. How can I diagnose why this is happening and correct it?

Comment: Do you have anything funny in your logs (in /var/log)? Anything strange in `dmesg`?

Comment: It's quite long file. I can't see nothing funny there at first sight.

Comment: When that happens, look at the end of the various log files in /var/log (and possibly sub-directories) - they are usually timestamped so you can focus on the time the problem occurred.

Comment: I think this is similar to my problem. Do you have an Intel's graphic card?

Comment: @Mat OK I try it, but there are many files.

Comment: @Yotam I have `ATI mobility radeon 9700`.

Comment: sorry, can't help you

Answer (score 4):

there were some bugs in 10.04 related to the X-server. occasionally, some processes would try to render objects in such a way as to cause X to crash.  GDM will notice this, and restart X, presenting the login screen again.

Fix is to generate an xorg.conf file, and then update that file to use a different acceleration method.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to access the first virtual console, and login.  Once you're there, you'll stop gdm, generate the xorg.conf file, and restart gdm.

```
sudo service gdm stop
sudo Xorg -configure
sudo service gdm start
```

Now that the xorg.conf file exists, make two small changes to set the following options:

```
Option "RenderAccel" "False"
```

and

```
Option "AccelMethod" "XAA"
```

Without knowing what kind of hardware you are using, you may have to fiddle around with the *AccelMethod* setting.  If you have intel hardware, you could try setting it to "UXA".  You can also try "EXA".  Check your default.

Comment: Does not break Xorg on Zorin OS 10, i have yet to reproduce cirumstances that trigger these crashes to see if it works.